# Folder right click menu(Only Folder)

Tags: c#, shell, directory, contextmenu

See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/SimpleContextMenu.aspx).What should i use instead of "Jpegfile" in the sample to represent folders?
I don't want Drives,Recyclebin,Computer(My computer in XP),My Documents(in xp),etc. to be included too. I want my right click menu entry to be added to folders' right click menu only.
Thanks and Regards.
Please note: **I can't use "Folder" since it includes recyclebin too.**
*AKGMA*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, you have no choice but to use Folder. There is no other file association key that does not include Recycle Bin. If you want to choose the type of folder your menu options are displayed on, you'll have to write an explorer extension.

Comment: I second this...have a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguideindex.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Anyway i found out that i can use a more general sentence as my context menu to include the recycle bin too.
Thanks anyway
Regards
AKGMA

Answer (score 2):

The "folders" you are talking about are actually directories; those that contain files. See [Difference between a Directory and a Folder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/16/10129908.aspx) in the context of Windows.

To have your right-click context menu entry appear only for directories, add it under

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\]
```

instead of

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\].
```

---

**See Also:** [Post by steve.marks59](http://www.theeldergeek.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=41537&p=303627)

```
XP treats "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell" and 
"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell" Registry keys and values differently.

Sub keys and values of "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell" are displayed 
in both the Windows Explorer Left Pane Folders context menu and 
Windows Explorer Right Pane Folders context menu.

Sub keys and values of "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell" are only displayed 
in the Windows Explorer Left Pane Folders context menu. These items are 
displayed at the top of the menu.

The order of the items displayed in the Windows Explorer Left Pane Folders 
context menu is:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell

The order of the items displayed in the Windows Explorer Right Pane Folders 
context menu is:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\(Specific File ex. batfile)\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell
```

Answer (score 2):

Really late answer, but correct option is to use `Folder`, however to exclude RecyleBin and other stuff you need to create `REG_SZ` value called `AppliesTo` and set it to `System.FileName:?*`.